# Eigenvalues as they pertain to Factor Analysis and Principal Component Analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

My question is this: How do eigenvalues fit in to factor analysis?

A couple of things I'm already familiar with:

1. I have a degree in physics, and I know how to calculate eigenvalues
   and eigenvectors.
2. I know that eigenvectors are vectors that change by, at most, a
   scalar (eigenvalue) during an axis rotation, skew, stretch, or
   scissoring transformation.
3. I know that in the context of factor analysis, eigenvalues have
   something to do with factor loadings, correlation coefficients, or
   something.  Eigenvalues below some threshold mean that a factor does
   not contribute to a model much.

Can someone go into more detail and connect all these ideas for me?  How exactly did eigenvalues ever get involved in PCA or factor analysis?  And what values actually go into the matrix of which we will find the eigenvalues?

The reason for my confusion, is that most authors on factor analysis and PCA do not go into the details, and say just to do it with R or SAS (or whatever statistical modeling package) and state that the mathematical details are beyond the scope of the book or class.